# Mount local directory in docker

Tags: docker, next.js, docker-compose

I work on an nextjs app, which I would like to containerize for production

the `docker-compose.yml` file looks like this:

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  app:
    container_name: webapp
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - webapp-volume:/app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
volumes:
  webapp-volume:
```

The `Dockerfile` looks like this:

```
FROM node:14-alpine

WORKDIR .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["start.sh"]
```

`start.sh` script is this:

```
#!/bin/sh

npm install

npm run build

npm start
```

When I create the image and inspect the container, there is nothing in the `/app` directory. What am I doing wrong?

I also created an Volume in the Volume folder. Does it need a certain mount?

Comment: At a start, it doesn't look like you `COPY` anything at all into your image, even the `start.sh` script.  You should `RUN npm install` and `RUN npm build` just once in your Dockerfile instead of repeating it every time the container starts, and there shouldn't be `volumes:` at all.  Docker has a specific [Build your Node image](https://docs.docker.com/language/nodejs/build-images/) tutorial that walks through this process.

Comment: How would you consider code changes?

Comment: Rebuild the image, have your CI system push it to a registry with a new tag, delete the existing container and create a new container with the new image.  (Especially since you say "production" in the first line.)

Comment: But this is not what I want. Its to heavy for small code changes.

Comment: If you just want to run code that lives locally on your host, and you don't have a CI system that runs tests and other automation before pushing things to production, then it will probably be easier to directly run Node without involving Docker at all.

Answer (score 0):

I changed to hardcoded path instead of volumes. This works